# How To Create A Java Graph File from .txt file

Tags: java, graph

I am trying to create a graph file .I have to read in values from a .gra file(which I think is a .txt file).We were told to tokenise lines based on a space in the format `<vertex> <name> <x-coord> <y-coord>`,same for edge

I had a look at a couple of related questions,but still cant find the answer.

Here's the code I was given:

```
        public EdgeListVertex(V element) {
            this.element = element;
        }

        @Override
        public V element() {
            return element;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return element.toString();
        }
    }

    private class EdgeListEdge implements Edge<E> {
        Position<EdgeListEdge> position;
        E element;
        EdgeListVertex start, end;


        public EdgeListEdge(EdgeListVertex start, EdgeListVertex end, E element) {
            this.start = start;
            this.end = end;
            this.element = element;
        }

        @Override
        public E element() {
            return element;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return element.toString();
        }
    }

    private List<EdgeListVertex> vertices;
    private List<EdgeListEdge> edges;


    public EdgeListGraph() {
        vertices = new LinkedList<EdgeListVertex>();
        edges = new LinkedList<EdgeListEdge>();

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public Vertex<V>[] endVertices(Edge<E> e) {
        EdgeListEdge edge = (EdgeListEdge) e;
        Vertex<V>[] endpoints = (Vertex<V>[]) new Vertex[2];
        endpoints[0] = edge.start;
        endpoints[1] = edge.end;
        return endpoints;
    }

    @Override
    public Vertex<V> opposite(Vertex<V> v, Edge<E> e) {
        Vertex<V>[] endpoints = endVertices(e);
        if (endpoints[0].equals(v)) {
            return endpoints[1];
        } else if (endpoints[1].equals(v)) {
            return endpoints[0];
        }
        throw new InvalidVertexException();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areAdjacent(Vertex<V> v, Vertex<V> w) {
        for (EdgeListEdge edge: edges) {
            if ((edge.start.equals(v)) && (edge.end.equals(w))) return true;
            if ((edge.end.equals(v)) && (edge.start.equals(w))) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public V replace(Vertex<V> v, V x) {
        EdgeListVertex vertex = (EdgeListVertex) v;
        V temp = vertex.element;
        vertex.element = x;
        return temp;
    }

    @Override
    public E replace(Edge<E> e, E x) {
        EdgeListEdge edge = (EdgeListEdge) e;
        E temp = edge.element;
        edge.element = x;
        return temp;
    }

    @Override
    public Vertex<V> insertVertex(V v) {
        EdgeListVertex vertex = new EdgeListVertex(v);
        Position<EdgeListVertex> position = vertices.insertLast(vertex);
        vertex.position = position;
        return vertex;
    }

    @Override
    public Edge<E> insertEdge(Vertex<V> v, Vertex<V> w, E o) {
        EdgeListEdge edge = new EdgeListEdge((EdgeListVertex) v, (EdgeListVertex) w, o);
        Position<EdgeListEdge> position = edges.insertLast(edge);
        edge.position = position;
        return edge;
    }

    @Override
    public V removeVertex(Vertex<V> v) {
        Iterator<Edge<E>> it = incidentEdges(v).iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) it.remove();

        EdgeListVertex vertex = (EdgeListVertex) v;
        vertices.remove(vertex.position);
        return vertex.element;
    }

    @Override
    public E removeEdge(Edge<E> e) {
        EdgeListEdge edge = (EdgeListEdge) e;
        edges.remove(edge.position);
        return edge.element;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Edge<E>> incidentEdges(Vertex<V> v) {
        LinkedList<Edge<E>> list = new LinkedList<Edge<E>>();

        for (EdgeListEdge edge : edges) {
            if (edge.start.equals(v)) list.insertLast(edge);
            if (edge.end.equals(v)) list.insertLast(edge);
        }

        return list;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Vertex<V>> vertices() {
        LinkedList<Vertex<V>> list = new LinkedList<Vertex<V>>();
        for (EdgeListVertex vertex : vertices) {
            list.insertLast(vertex);
        }
        return list;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Edge<E>> edges() {
        LinkedList<Edge<E>> list = new LinkedList<Edge<E>>();
        for (EdgeListEdge edge : edges) {
            list.insertLast(edge);
        }
        return list;
    }

}
```

Any tips?

Comment: What is your specific question?

Comment: ooks like your code snippet was truncated at the top.  If homework, please use "homework" tag.  Presumably you have questions about the I/O involved, but you'll need to show what you tried first.

Comment: @jzd Ok.My specific question is how to start,or approach the creation of the graph.I am thinking to use a scanner object,then use something like BufferedReader object(am not sure if there's such in JAVA API),then use readLine().After doing that,either cast the value read into element of the EdgeListEdge object(or EdgeListVertex object).I am not very good at Java Syntax though,and woould appreciate any hint,tips..@bkail I am not sure what I/O is and which code snippet was truncated(the syntax for vertex creation or the start of the class)

Answer (score 0):

A good approach might be to create a new class with fields for vertex, name and coordinates. Then read in the data from a scanner into an [ArrayList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) of the class you just created. After this, you could just pass the ArrayList into whatever you are using for graphing (which might require a few tweaks).

Example scanner code (**untested**):

```
File graphFile = new File(filepath);
Scanner graphScanner = new Scanner(graphFile);
```

Then, to read from the scanner (**untested**):

```
ArrayList<graphClass> dataPoints = new ArrayList<graphClass>(); //you will have to make graphClass
while(graphScanner.hasNextLine()) {
    dataPoints.add(new graphClass(graphScanner.nextDouble(), graphScanner.next(), graphScanner.nextDouble(), graphScanner.nextDouble()); //assuming constructor of graphClass takes vertex, name, x, y in that order
```

I hope this helps.